# Lua 5.2::Create a different environment for each script

Tags: lua

This is a simplified version of the problem that Im having:

[ bot0.lua ]

```
function OnHit(bot)

// Where the bot structure and vec3 
// generated using SWIG and registered to a 
// "global" lua_State that I maintain.
bot.color = vec3( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
end;
```

[bot1.lua]

```
function OnHit(bot)

bot.color = vec3( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
end;
```

At loading time, for each script I first do the following (pseudo code):

```
bot->script->L = lua_newthread( <Global lua_State where vec3 etc... are registered> )

luaL_loadbuffer( bot->script->L, botXXX.lua ...

lua_call( bot->script->L, ...
```

Then at runtime from my program when a bot get hit I call:

```
luaL_dostring( bot->script->L, "OnHit(GetBot(\"<the bot name>\")" );
```

(Where GetBot is also a function registered in the global lua_State).

The problem is that the bot always become green since bot1.lua OnHit is in the last bot file loaded. I thought by using lua_newthread I will be able to have a new definition of OnHit for each "thread" created that will assign the proper color to the bot since Im using a different lua_State when using luaL_dostring. But in fact the lastest OnHit loaded will overwrite the previous one in the the global lua_State environement.

My question is: How can I create a different environment for each script so that the correct OnHit will be called for the correct bot->script->L and where I can still have access to all the functions (such as my vec3,GetBot etc... functions) that are registered inside the "global" lua_State environment that I create?

[edit]

After more research I think what I need is to be able to "sandbox" in C. Am I right?

[edit]

Actually not really sandboxing, since I want to that if the look up fail in the script environment, the lookup is made to the global environment. Is it even possible?

Comment: This problem could be solved by OOP approach.  Let each bot be a table with private `OnHit` function like this one `function bot:OnHit() self.color = vec3( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0) end`.  Then simply call `GetBot(\"<the bot name>\"):OnHit()`.

Comment: Im not sure Im getting it cuz GetBot is a C function that return a bot pointer... Can you elaborate?

Comment: According to your script, `GetBot` is Lua function.

Answer (score 0):

bot0.lua

```
local bot = {}

function bot:OnHit()
  self.color = vec3( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
end

return bot
```

---

bot1.lua

```
local bot = {}

function bot:OnHit()
  self.color = vec3( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
end

return bot
```

---

main.lua

```
all_bots = {[0]=require"bot0", require"bot1"}

function GetBot(name)
  if name == "bot #0" then
    return all_bots[0]
  elseif name == "bot #1" then
    return all_bots[1]
  end
end
```

inside C program

```
luaL_dostring( bot->script->L, "GetBot('<the bot name>'):OnHit()" );
```